# Selecting Certain Keys,Values From List of Python Dictionaries to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a problem with manipulating a list of dictionaries into something more digestible to write to a csv.  For example, I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
dict_example = [{'id':1,'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},{'id':1,'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]
```

Ideally, I would like a csv out of this that would be:

```
id,key1,key2,key1,key2
1,value1,value2,value3,value4
```

Basically, I would like to find out the easiest way to do this.  This list I am working with is much larger.  Additionally, for each 'id' there are 4 dictionaries representing different values I would like all in one row for each 'id'.

Any thoughts? I can think of ways to do this by extracting values into other forms, but not by leaving them in the dictionary and then writing it to CSV.

EDIT:

I now need to figure out what data format may be most useful.  For each 'id',  there are different 'stages' where the value for 'key1' and 'key2' are different.  The ID is persistent.

What would be a useful dict to store this in?

Example as it exists now, with more clarity:

```
dict = dict_example = [{'id':1,'stage':'stage1','key2':'value1'},{'id':1,'stage':'stage2','key2':'value2'}]
```

Comment: So, if there was another dict... you'd have key1,key2 again? Doesn't seem a very usable format...

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I do need to reconsider how I am storing.  The problem I am running into is that I am taking snap shots of the data at different points.  I will update with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group on certain criteria - in your case, the `'id'`:

```
import itertools

d = [{'id':1,'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},{'id':1,'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}, \
        {'id':1,'key4':'value5'}, {'id':2,'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]

for id, group in itertools.groupby(d, lambda x : x['id']):
    key_line = 'id'
    values_line = str(id)
    for g in group:
        for key in sorted(g.keys()):
            if key == 'id':
                continue
            key_line += ',{0}'.format(key)
            values_line += ',{0}'.format(g[key])

    print key_line
    print values_line
```

This will output

```
id,key1,key2,key1,key2,key4
1,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
id,key1,key2
2,value3,value4
```

...etc

for each id in your dictionary.  I'm still not sure if it's a very usable output.  You might want to consider reorganizing how you are storing your data in the first place.